# d3 textwrap to incorporate <b> and <em> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm building a graphic, and I'd like to add an annotation layer that both wraps the text and also incorporates HTML tags.

For example, I'd like to input:

```
vis.append('text')
   .attr("text-anchor", "left")
   .text('left side <b>left side</b> left side left side')
   .call(wrap, 100);
```

which is modeled off of MBostock's [generic text wrapper](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321), and have `wrap()` be smart enough to both wrap this text, and bold it on a word-by-word basis, possibly even across multiple lines.

In other words, I want it to be able to mark, if necessary:

left side **left

side** left side
left side left ...

MBostock's text wrapper screws this up because:

1. It calls `words.reverse()`, thus confusing the natural open-tag/close-tag
2. It relies on `<text>` and `<tspan>` elements, which to the best of my knowledge do not support inline `<b>` or `<em>` tags. (They do support CSS styles like `font-weight` and `font-style`, but I'm not sure how to do that on a word-by-word basis, just on a tspan basis. And I'm not willing to use `foreignObject` since it doesn't seem to have wide browser support.)

I'm not sure what the best workaround is. Has anyone dealt with this issue at all?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Did you consider using a div from outside of the svg (according to the dom), but with absolute coordinates to make it appear inside? It may or may not fit your needs, but if it does it's probably the simplest option.

Comment: I did consider that, but because this is being incorporated into a larger CMS, and needs to be reactive, I'm thinking that keeping it as a single SVG might cause less headaches down the road? I'm not sure..

Comment: It must be a large project indeed if you'd rather write a parser now than keep a tricky part around. So yes, your solution is best...  especially since you've done the parser now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have a rough solution. There's probably a cleaner and more elegant way of doing this, but the general idea is as follows:

1. Preserve Mike's `<tspan>` approach to measuring the length of text to determine when to break lines.
2. But, append a `<tspan>` for each word *within* the larger `<tspan>` per line
3. Then, to style bold and italics, we keep track of the state of the text thus far (if a `<b>` or `<em>` tag is open) and use the `font-style` and `font-weight` CSS attributes accordingly.

The following code does this, and also handles multiple lagging or separate `<br>` (not leading `<br>`):

```
function wrap(text, width, block_id) {
  text.each(function() {  
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        x = text.attr("x"),
        dy = 0
        tspan = text.text(null)
                      .append("tspan")
                      .attr("x", x)
                      .attr("y", y)
                      .attr("dy", dy + "em");

    word_id_counter = 0
    bold_state = false
    italic_state = false
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      // change state to bold 
      if (word.split('<b>').length > 1){
        bold_state = true
        word = word.replace('<b>','')
      }
      //change state to italic
      if (word.split('<em>').length > 1){
        italic_state = true
        word = word.replace('<em>','')
      }

      tspan.append('tspan')
            .attr('id', 'word' + '_' + word_id_counter + '_' + block_id)
            .attr('font-weight', bold_state ? 'bold' : 'normal')
            .attr('font-style', italic_state ? 'italic' : 'normal')
            .text(
              word.replace('</b>','').replace('</em>','').replace(new RegExp('<br>', 'g'), '')
              + " "
            );

        // handle overflow
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() >= width) {
        d3.select("#" + 'word' + '_' + word_id_counter + '_' + block_id).remove();

        // handle edge case where line break and overflow occur at same time
        word = word.replace('<br>','')

        tspan = text.append("tspan")
                      .attr("x", x)
                      .attr("y", y)
                      .attr('id', 'wrap-text')
                      .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")

        tspan.append('tspan')
              .attr('id', 'word' + '_' + word_id_counter + '_' + block_id)
              .attr('font-weight', bold_state ? 'bold' : 'normal')
              .attr('font-style', italic_state ? 'italic' : 'normal')
              .text(word.replace('</em>','').replace('</b>','').replace(new RegExp('<br>', 'g'), '') + " ");
        }

      // handle newline (can handle multiple)
      if ((total_br = word.split('<br>').length - 1) > 0){
        lineNumber = lineNumber + total_br
        tspan = text.append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr('id', 'wrap-text')
          .attr("dy", lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
      }

      //handle close bold: change bold_state back to normal
      if (word.split('</b>').length > 1){
        bold_state = false
      }

      //handle close italics: change state back to normal
      if (word.split('</em>').length > 1){
        italic_state = false
      }

      word_id_counter = word_id_counter + 1
    }
  });
}
```

**Sample**:

When run on this:

```
  this.vis.append('text')
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .text('left1 side1 left2 side2 <b>left3 side3 left4 side4 <em>left5 side5</b> left6<br><br> side6 left7</em> side7 left8 side8 left9 side9 left10 side10 left11 side11 left12 side12')
        .call(wrap, 100, 1);
```

The output is this:

[image: sample]